# Change the line height of the text inside a label with Nativescript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm trying to increase the line height of the text inside a label.
I've found this code sample: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1664#issuecomment-218977478

that is supposed to do the trick, and now I'm trying to implement it.

Here is what I have so far:

the xml file (loaded from a tabView):

```
<ListView id="news-feed" items="{{ news }}" loaded="onLoaded" itemLoading="onItemLoading" separatorColor="#f4f4f4">
   <ListView.itemTemplate>
   <GridLayout backgroundColor="#f4f4f4">
    <StackLayout tap="openInWebview" class="news-card">
     <Label text="{{ headline }}" textWrap="true" class="headline" />
     <Label id="textLabel" text="{{ lead }}" textWrap="true" />
    </StackLayout>
   </GridLayout>
   </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The function triggered by the event itemLoading:

```
function onItemLoading(args) {
page = args.object;

var myLabel = page.getViewById("textLabel");
labelLineHeight(myLabel)

}
```

And of course the function as described in the Github issue linked above:

```
function labelLineHeight(nsLabel) {

// console.dump(nsLabel)


if(page.ios){

    var label = nsLabel.ios;
    var attributedString;

    if(label.attributedText){
        attributedString = label.attributedText;
    }
    else{
        attributedString=NSMutableAttributedString.alloc().initWithString(label.text);
    }
    var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.alloc().init();
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5;
    var range= NSMakeRange(0, label.text.length);
    attributedString.addAttributeValueRange(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle, range);
    label.attributedText = attributedString;
}
if(page.android){
    var label = nsLabel.android;
    //Default spacing is 20% of text size
    //setLineSpacing(add,multiplyby);
    label.setLineSpacing(12, 1);
}   
}
```

And the error message I get:

```
[45842]: file:///app/mainTabs/tabNews/tabNews.js:40:28: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nsLabel.ios')
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

What I have noticed is that the way you are assigning an id to you label is not correct. The reason is that way you will have multiple IDs for each of your list-view items with identical ID. You should dynamically generate different IDs for you labels inside the item template of the list-view (for example: by giving them id-name with unique index at the end).

Another thing is that you are trying to get the ID in onItemLoading. Do that in the **loaded** event of the parent view (on the list-view, the parent view or even the page loaded event with the onLoaded callback).